# Error en SP MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo el siguiente error:

> `#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca '' en la linea 6`

Muestro código

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spF_detalleVenta_one1(cod int)
BEGIN
SELECT d.CodigoVenta, d.CodigoProducto, p.Nombre, d.Cantidad, d.Descuento 
FROM detalleventa d 
inner join producto p on p.CodigoProducto = d.CodigoProducto
WHERE d.CodigoVenta = cod;
END;
```

Alguna idea de por que no corre?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que se esta presentando es por que tienes error en la sintaxis al momento de crear el `stored` te falto poner el `delimiter`, por lo que tu código quedaria de la siguiente manera:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE spF_detalleVenta_one1(cod int)
BEGIN
SELECT d.CodigoVenta, d.CodigoProducto, p.Nombre, d.Cantidad, d.Descuento 
FROM detalleventa d 
inner join producto p on p.CodigoProducto = d.CodigoProducto
WHERE d.CodigoVenta = cod;
END //
```

Mayor información [documentación oficial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) de MySQL.

Comment: por cada procedure debo agregar el delimeter?

Comment: Si ya que estas indicando la delimitación de cada una de las sentencias a ejecutar